# Recording Audio in Android Televison Application

Tags: android, audio, avaudioplayer, audio-recording, television

I am designing an android application that will work on as many devices as possible, including televisions.

My application records audio (among other things)

One downside of TV's is that they do not have audio recording capabilities, (not that i can see or find via Google searching).

Do i have any options and/or workarounds for audio recording/playback on TV's from within my application?

Comment: What do you intend to record on a device that doesn't have a microphone? The current audio output?

Comment: Micheal - Thanks for taking the time to a). point out a TV doesn't have a microphone (which i stated in my question) and b). ignoring my request for "any other options/workarounds". what i want to record is secondary once i've solved the "how to record issue?"

Comment: I wasn't criticising your question. I genuinely wanted to know what you want to use as the audio source, because I feel that it's going to be hard for anyone to answer the question otherwise.

Comment: I need to record my apps users voice. As Samsung TV's appear to be shipped with the Skype application (using an Add-On Camera with built in microphones) i would expect android apps could detect these additional devices connected to the TV and make use of them. Am i wrong?

Comment: The TV Camera appears to be attached via USB. Depending on how Samsung has implemented things you might be able to listen for USB connection broadcasts (I don't remember if those are sticky though) and simply record from the `MIC` audio source. Have you looked at Samsung's [Smart TV SDK](http://www.samsungdforum.com/devtools/sdkdownload)? Perhaps it contains some information on this subject.